# SharePoint workflow development

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I get a weird error message when trying to create new Visual Studio 2010 project of type "SharePoint 2010 Sequential workflow":

"The SharePoint site at "somesite" is missing a target, task, or history list. Each of these lists is required to associate a workflow template. Please create a list and then launch this wizard."

I already have two projects in my Visual Studio 2010 solution: MyListsDef with many SharePoint custom lists defined and MySiteDef with site definition to populate those lists when new SharePoint site is created.

I have to create SharePoint workflow project for some of my lists in Visual Studio 2010.

I made some steps prior creation of third (SharePoint Sequential workflow) project in my solution:

1. Compile and package both MyListsDef and MySiteDef,
2. Install both MyListsDef.wsp and MySiteDef.wsp as solutions on my SharePoint 2010 server,
3. Create new SharePoint 2010 site based on MySiteDef template,
4. Create new Visual Studio 2010 project "SharePoint 2010 Sequential workflow" with reference to SharePoint site, created in step #3.

However, I always get the error "... is missing a target, task, or history list." every time I select a site, created in step #3, as a reference in a sequential workflow wizard in Visual Studio 2010 in step #4.

What does this error mean and what lists are missing?
What I am doing wrong?
What is a typical way to develop SharePoint workflows with custom lists?

Thanks in advance,
Sal

Answer (score 1):

Sal,

This happens when required lists for workflows are not created.

Do the below to make it work :

1. **ACTIVATE** any feature thats relaetd to workflow (1st at SITE COLL level then at WEB level)
2. Go to the site and select a list
3. Click on **WORKFLOW SETTINGS** in the **RIBBON**
4. Then **ADD A WORKFLOW** and then select some workflow (ex: approval)
5. **SAVE** it

The above process will create required lists for workflow processing.
Now you can continue with Visual Studio work.

Comment: Is there no way to do this in Visual Studio? It can't be expected to do this manually for every list.

Comment: How can we activate it? What are the esteps to do it?